# is there any way to hide :value from datalist but sent the value by using POST method?

Tags: html, forms, vue.js

I am creating a an Editable combox , Where people can  "Search" "Select" or "Edit,insert" new value ,
I am using Input and Datalist for this.

Please see this  in jsfiddle,

https://jsfiddle.net/fosiul/j097mq3u/10/

the problem is : its creating 2 line in the combox (datalist) first line is showing value of ledger_object_id and second line is .ledger_object_name

I need to

```
a) hide the value of .ledger_object_id from the combox, only show  the name of ledger_object_name
```

however when sending the value by POST, i want to sent the  ledger_object_id inside the function `store_purchase_and_sale()`

is this possible ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The `datalist` HTML element is not the same as `select` element - see the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/datalist)
The `option`s inside a `datalist` always show their `value` attribute in bold on the first line - and if there is some content inside the `option` tag it is shown in lighter font on the second line. You can not change this behavior - so you can either

- use the `object_name` as `value` and leave `option` tags empty (if `object_name`s are unique you can then map them to their `object_id`)
- or use something else than `datalist`

Comment: the object_id is uniq , but object_name is not unique, is there any way to map it ? object_id with object_name ?
if not what other option do i have ?

Comment: If the name is not unique you do not have a chance and will have to use another solution, e.g. something from https://awesome-vue.js.org/components-and-libraries/ui-components.html

Comment: thanks I am quite in Vue, just had a look at the link you sent, do you think this one will work?
https://github.com/sagalbot/vue-select
where i show object_name, and pass the object_id to the function + Edit option ? will it work ?

Comment: You are the developer - only you can decide whether it will work in your particular case or not. There are plenty to choose from - if one does not work, try another one.

Comment: Thanks i looked at that.. but its seems i am having trouble to understand which one will give Ability to EDIT, search and Select both , i am just learning vue, but this requiremnt came up,  if you know which one might has this capability that will be great,

Comment: Usually drop-down lists are used to select something from a predefined list of values, either displaying the raw values or their user-friendly equivalent. Sometimes there is an ability for searching/filtering inside the predefined list - but it is rather awkward to edit the predefined list in-place. Standard UX/UI practice is to edit the predefined list(s) somewhere else rather than in-place.